# Showing that f,g are invertible if $A$ is a finite set and $f,g: A\to A$ such that $f\circ g$ is invertible

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, function-and-relation-composition

> Let $A$ be a finite set and $f,g: A\to A$ such that $f\circ g$ is invertible.
>
> 1. Prove f,g are invertible.
> 2. Prove that if $A$ is an infinite set, it doesn't mean that f,g are invertible.

I get that since $f\circ g$ is a bijection, then $g$ is an injection, $f$ is a surjection. What's left is to show that $f$ is an injection, $g$ is a surjection.

Now I just don't know what to with the fact that $A$ is a finite set...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717597/let-x-and-y-be-finite-non-empty-sets-such-that-x-y-show-that-a-function?rq=1

Comment: https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Mapping_from_Set_to_Itself_is_Injection_Iff_Surjection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** a function $A \to A$ from a finite set $A$ to itself is injective if and only if it is surjective.

For 2., let us try $A = \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. You want $f$ to be surjective but not injective. An example would be $f: x \mapsto \lfloor x/2 \rfloor$. Now $g: x \mapsto 2x$ is injective but not surjective... What is $f \circ g$?